# Why can't I access my bash prompt in a Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, bash

In my `.bash_profile` I have:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  source $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
  GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
  git_prompt='$(__git_ps1)'
fi
export PS1="\[\e[33m\]  \d \t \w$git_prompt\n\[\e[m\]\\$ "
export MYTESTVAR="hello world"
```

I have a Ruby script `foo.rb` that contains:

```
`source ~/.bash_profile`
puts `printenv`
puts `echo $PS1`
puts `echo $MYTESTVAR`
```

When I run `ruby foo.rb` the `printenv` command lists all environment variables, and the `$MYTESTVAR` line correctly returns `hello world`.

However, `$PS1` does not show up. Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

> $MYTESTVAR line correctly returns hello world.
>   $PS1 does not show up.

Indeed, you're right. Most variables work fine, but "PS1" in particular fails:

```
$ PS1=ps1 TEST1=test1 ruby -e 'puts `echo $PS1 and $TEST1`'
and test1
```

> Why is this?

In Ruby, as you're probably aware, `` `somestring` `` executes `somestring` in a shell, as if you in C had opened a pipe to `execl("/bin/sh", "-c", somestring, NULL)`.

On many systems, `/bin/sh` is provided by `bash`. Bash has this snippet in [its initialization code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c#n624):

```
  /* Execute the start-up scripts. */

  if (interactive_shell == 0)
    {
      unbind_variable ("PS1");
      unbind_variable ("PS2");
      interactive = 0;
```

In other words, it explicitly removes "PS1" and "PS2" because these variables are only intended for use with interactive shells.

On other systems where `/bin/bash` is provided by `dash`, as many modern Debian-based distros default to, you instead get the result you expected:

```
$ PS1=ps1 TEST1=test1 ruby -e 'puts `echo $PS1 $TEST1`'
ps1 and test1
```

The reason why your `` `source ~/.bash_profile` `` doesn't fix this is that each `` `backtick command` `` runs in a separate shell. Variables set in one is not reflected in the other.

If you just want the variable as exported by your shell, you should do what @anujm suggests and get it directly with `ENV['PS1']`. Not only is this easier and more robust, it's also a thousand times faster.

If you want the variable as set in your `.bash_profile`, regardless of how you ran your script, you can do both sourcing and printing in the same shell:

```
puts `bash -c 'source ~/.bash_profile; printf "%s" "$PS1"'`
```

Comment: But it is more complicated than that because there five separate processes involved and each has its own environment.

Comment: I didn't catch that part. Updated.